# Access Declaration of Base Class Overloaded Method

Tags: c++, overloading

Given that we have overloaded methods in base class, and a derived class that was inherited as private/protected.

1. Can we restore only one/several of the original access level of the overloaded methods?
2. On GCC 4.4.0 i try to put the base methods under protected access, then inherited it using private access. When i try to restore the access level to public, it works! Is this how its suppose to work? or is it a bug on the compiler? To my understanding, restoring access level shouldn't be able to be used to promote or demote a member's access level.

Code snippet :

```
class base {
  public:
    void method() {}
    void method(int x) {}
  protected:
    void method2() {}
};

class derived : private base {
  public:
    base::method; // Here, i want to restore only the none parameterized method
    base::method2; // method2 is now public??
};
```

Comment: BTW- is a declaration like `base::method` exactly equivalent to `using base::method`?

Comment: @Kos, yes but it's no longer valid to say `base::method;` in C++0x. It was removed by the n3225 draft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing accessibility of inherited functions through a `using` declaration cannot be done selectively on given overload for the simple reason that a `using` declaration only introduces a ***name*** into the declarative region and that by definition, functions overloads share the same name.

The only alternative I see here is to use trivial forwarding functions :

```
class derived : private base
{
public:
    void method() { base::method(); }

    using base::method2; // method2 is now public
    // method(int) stays inaccessible
};
```

I'm not quite sure I understand your second question, but yes : you can change base members accessibility in a derived class through `using` declarations.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.. combine this with @DeadMG answer for second question and we can mark the question solved..

Answer (score 1):

You don't *restore* access, per se.  You *set* access.  As you are doing above, you can explicitly set the access for any method, including ones previously declared as `private`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be impossible to prevent protected methods from being public if the derived class wanted it so, as you could just write a minor wrapper and done. `private` is another matter.

Comment: akh... yes.. that make sense.. thanks.. I was reading a chapter from " C++ Complete References 4th Ed.", and there's a paragraph stating : "You can use an access declaration to restore the access rights of public and protected
members. However, you cannot use an access declaration to raise or lower a member's
access status. For example, a member declared as private in a base class cannot be
made public by a derived class. (If C++ allowed this to occur, it would destroy its
encapsulation mechanism!)".. So I think he meant for public and protected to be considered the same level..